# android associative array from from php (which get through mysql) and return to android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on app which requires some dynamic data from php/MySQL. Have a look at code:

```
    void getJsonRequest(String url,final LayoutInflater inflater) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, null);
    final TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.main_msg_gallery);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String id = response.getString("album_name");
                        t.setText(id);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    t.setText(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

I call this function in a fragment. I get array result successfully. But i cannot get specific result.[image]

I want to get every column of every row separately. Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: seriously? still 2 views and no reply after 4 hours?

Comment: The message says exactly what's wrong, you're treating a JSONArray like it's a JSONObject.